# Augmenting the the 2nd column in an N x 2 array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have generated noise with `RandomVariate` and am trying to add it to the y values only of a list of {x, y}-coordinates. I'm looking for a general way to add the noise (one-dimensional list) to the y-values of my list (data) such that given:

```
noise = {α, β, γ};
data = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}};
```

the result is

```
{{1, a + α}, {2, b + β}, {3, c + γ}}
```

I could do this with `Table` in what feels like a really inelegant process, but is there a way to do it in a simple algebraic command with only `Take`? For example, I know I can take the second column of data only with `data[[All,2]]`, but the resulting list will include only the y values. I would prefer not to have to split up and recombine the lists.

#### Edit

To clarify, I would really like to be able to do this without defining additional variables.

Comment: `data + Transpose[PadLeft[{noise}, {2, Automatic}]]`?

Comment: Must be a duplicate, `data[[;; , 2]] += noise; data`.

Comment: @Kuba, I agree that it has to be a dupe, but searching is proving to be troublesome...

Comment: @J.M. yep, we should require to include `FullForm` of an answer to list-manipulation topics ;)

Comment: related: [42258](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42258/5478)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a community wiki where we can accumulate answers.

```
noise = {α, β, γ};
data = {{1, a}, {2, b}, {3, c}};
```

**J.M.**

```
data + Transpose[PadLeft[{noise}, {2, Automatic}]]
```

> `{{1, a + α}, {2, b + β}, {3, c + γ}}`

**m_goldberg**

```
MapThread[#1 + {0, #2} &, {data, noise}]
```

> `{{1, a + α}, {2, b + β}, {3, c + γ}}`

**Kuba**

```
data[[;; , 2]] += noise; data
```

> `{{1, a + α}, {2, b + β}, {3, c + γ}}`

**march**

A silly way that illustrates a clever trick I learned here:

```
Module[{i = 1},
  Replace[data, {a_, b_} :> {a, b + noise[[i++]]}, 2]]
```

**BoLe**

```
data + ({0, #} & /@ noise)
```

Comment: `data + ({0, #} & /@ noise)`

Answer (score 1):

Using the binary operator form of `Plus`,

```
plus[y_][x_]:=x+y
```

Makes it more readable than `(# + noise)&` in the following:

```
data // Transpose // MapAt[plus[noise], 2] // Transpose
```

> {{1, a + [Alpha]}, {2, b + [Beta]}, {3, c + [Gamma]}}

Answer (score 0):

```
f = # + ToExpression[
FromCharacterCode[{1, -1, 1}.Flatten[
   ToCharacterCode /@ {SymbolName[#], "a", "\[Alpha]"}]]] &

data /. u : (a | b | c) :> f[u]
```

Comment: What happens if some of the values of `a`, `b` and `c` are the same?  E.g. `a = b =1; c = 2` or even all `a = b = c = 3`.